# mobile-buy-sdk-android fails with error com.shopify.buy3.GraphHttpError

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, shopify

Below is the code and error message

Error Message:

**"error com.shopify.buy3.GraphHttpError: HTTP 403 Forbidden
"**

403 error indicates that I am not properly authenticating the request, What am I doing wrong here? 
The code

```
 OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor())
            .build();
 GraphClient gl =  GraphClient.builder(this)
            .shopDomain("<shop name>.myshopify.com")
            .accessToken("myAPIKey")
            .httpClient(httpClient)
            .httpCache(new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "/http"), 10 * 1024 * 1024) 
            .defaultHttpCachePolicy(HttpCachePolicy.CACHE_FIRST.expireAfter(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) // cached response valid by default for 5 minutes
            .build();

Storefront.QueryRootQuery query = Storefront.query(new Storefront.QueryRootQueryDefinition() {
        @Override public void define(final Storefront.QueryRootQuery rootQueryBuilder) {
            rootQueryBuilder.shop(new Storefront.ShopQueryDefinition() {
                @Override public void define(final Storefront.ShopQuery shopQueryBuilder) {
                    shopQueryBuilder.privacyPolicy(new Storefront.ShopPolicyQueryDefinition() {
                        @Override
                        public void define(final Storefront.ShopPolicyQuery policyQueryBuilder) {
                            policyQueryBuilder.body();
                            policyQueryBuilder.url();
                            policyQueryBuilder.title();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });

 QueryGraphCall call = cl.queryGraph(query);

    call.enqueue(new GraphCall.Callback<Storefront.QueryRoot>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull GraphResponse<Storefront.QueryRoot> response) {
            String body = response.data().getShop().getPrivacyPolicy().getBody();
            Log.v(TAG,"boby : " + body);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull GraphError error) {
            Log.v(TAG,"error " + error.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: `compile 'com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy3:3.1.1'
compile 'com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy3-pay-support:1.0.2'`

Comment: Yes, I have added in build gradle.,I have edited my post, previously I was doing mistake in sending domain name.Now I have corrected and got this HTTP 403 Forbidden now

Comment: Need API Token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HTTP 403 Forbidden

Read [**`Private authentication`**](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/private-authentication)

Before you can authenticate a private application to Shopify, you need to generate the required credentials from the Shopify admin of the store that you want to connect with your application.

> If you want to use the Storefront API, then select Allow this app to
>   access your storefront data using the Storefront API. This will
>   generate a Storefront access token.

Comment: It worked after replacing API key with Storefront access token ,Thanks Amiya